# UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-crash-reporting

I added the link of the image manually
this message appears, any help? :

This is the class :

```
public class Profil {
    private String nom,prenom, dateInscription, image, id_Personne ,id_Carte;

public Profil (){

}

public Profil(String nom, String prenom, String dateInscription, String image, String id_Personne, String id_Carte) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.dateInscription = dateInscription;
    this.image = image;
    this.id_Personne = id_Personne;
    this.id_Carte = id_Carte;
}
```

and this is the class :

```
public class Profil {
    private String nom,prenom, dateInscription, image, id_Personne ,id_Carte;

public Profil (){

}

public Profil(String nom, String prenom, String dateInscription, String image, String id_Personne, String id_Carte) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.dateInscription = dateInscription;
    this.image = image;
    this.id_Personne = id_Personne;
    this.id_Carte = id_Carte;
}



 public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Profil> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Profil>().setQuery(ProfilRef, Profil.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profil, ProfilViewHolder> Adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profil, ProfilViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfilViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Profil model){
                holder.txtProfilName.setText(model.getNom());
                holder.txtProfilLastName.setText(model.getPrenom());
                holder.txtProfilRegistration.setText("Registration Date  = "+model.getDateInscription());

                //  Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imageView);



            }
"Personne" : {
    "-LmK-O6zImymhKrGKyjm" : {
      "dateInscription" : "2019-06-02",
      "id_Carte" : "3",
      "id_Personne" : "3",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iotproject-f595a.appspot.com/o/Profil%20Image%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=aac5ff54-9374-425d-9a52-154be89f96cd",
      "nom" : "ELACHBI",
      "prenom" : "Mouhsine"
    },
```

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert
>   value of type java.lang.Long to String
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>           at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
>           at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
>           at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:35)
>           at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
>           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:106)
>           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 09-22
>   00:01:44.271 792-1463/mobildev.iosm.com.priot I/FirebaseCrash: Sending
>   crashes 09-22 00:01:44.281 792-1463/mobildev.iosm.com.priot
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 09-22
>   00:01:44.281 792-1463/mobildev.iosm.com.priot I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 09-22 00:01:45.981
>   792-1463/mobildev.iosm.com.priot I/FirebaseCrash: Response code: 200
>   09-22 00:01:45.981 792-1463/mobildev.iosm.com.priot E/FirebaseCrash:
>   Unable to parse Json response string to get message: No value for
>   crashes

Comment: Try to make your question concise and well-formatted.

Answer (score 1):

create getter and setter for variable and String method [retrieve-data from firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Comment: thank you for your answer but I already add the getters and setters